# Mongoose filter object in field_name

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az4Lk.png)

I want to list cars by username, how can i do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 db.cars.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "cars",
          },
        },
        {
          $match: { "cars.name": "Mustafa" },
        },
      ])
```

Working!!

Answer (score 0):

Need to use [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) operations to do that.

To retrieve documents from `mongosh`, open MongoDB Compass. Then open the `mongosh` terminal that is at the left bottom of the Compass window. 
Then, need to run this command to switch the database to the current one you are gonna retrieve the documents:

```
use arpaslanOto
```

Now, the current db is `alparslanOto`. Then write the `aggregate query` to filter the documents like this:

```js
db.cars.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "UserCarTable",
        },
      },
      {
        $match: { "UserCarTable.usernameField": username },
      },
]);
```

I hope it's useful for you